# Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setPosts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

Uploading images and data onto firebase and it's callback was fine.
But in the promise function I got the error of Can't find variable : setPosts which is defined by Actions on Redux
Here the

```
    [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setPosts]
- node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\Tabs\DefaultTabBar.js:1:328 in <global>
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

And the code

```
// For Media
  const onPresslaunchCameraMedia = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      console.log("============ Media Uploaded By Photo =============")
      console.log(result.uri)
      await setMediaData({...mediaData, country : userData.country})
      await uploadMedia(mediaData, result.uri)
      dispatch(addPost(mediaData));
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('Home'));
    }
  };
```

Using expo-cli for launching react-native app

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Forget to import the actions file on that page :)